# Simple validation with attribute pattern in HTML

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

I do not really mastered this, but i want to validation checks form HTML attribute, that is "pattern", this example my own:

```
<input type='text' pattern='[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+' />
```

This validates only one number. How can I validate a comma-separated list of numbers?

Comment: What is the requirement here? Please provide input strings you want to match and those you do not want to match.

Comment: what? i want to create HTML validation for my <input> tag, using by pattern. in some tag i want to using ONLY Commas and Number, just that.., i dont understand you problem @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, is `11,22,33,44,1,` or `1,,,,3` valid?

Comment: i want is 11,22,33,44, and not 1,,,,,3 :) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/082zsrym/).

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ADVANCE :) you can Answer my question and i up your answer @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: i can't understand, how you do that?, you can create regex by your self? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See my explanations. No need to be excited about it that much, it is just a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to validate a string of comma-separated numbers that meet your pattern.

Use

```
pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:,[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)*"
```

The pattern is anchored by default, so no need using `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

**Details**:

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `[0-9]*`  - 0+ digits
- `[.,]?` - an optional `.` or `,`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)*` - zero or more  sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+` - the number pattern (described above).

See a demo below:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:,[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)*" title=""/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```